# What is this screen and how to use it in my application?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, notifications, lockscreen

This screen display an authentification code even on the lock screen. 
I've googled it and found absolutely nothing about it. I even don't know the name of the component.

Is it possible to be a special push notification ?

**I need to know which class provide this view that is displayed on the lockscreen.**

[image: Special notification on lock screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer !

This is a "Class 0 sms", that is displayed as full screen by the OS.

> Class 0 SMS: This message is displayed on the mobile phone immediately
>   and a message delivery report is sent back to the SC. The message does
>   not have to be saved in the mobile phone or on the SIM card (unless
>   selected to do so by the mobile user). This type is also referred to
>   as Flash SMS.

See for details :
http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=544